# What is use of reference to reference in C++?

Tags: c++

I land into std::vector header and saw somethings which I do not understand.

```
    void push_back(_Ty&& _Val)
```

I can understand pointer to pointer, but is there anythings like reference to reference. What purpose it will serve?

May be I am asking very basic question, but this is something I see first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't a reference to a reference — such a thing doesn't exist. It's an r-value reference, which is new to C++11. There are plenty of references (excuse the pun) to this concept online (e.g., [here](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html)).

Comment: Thanks. C++ 11 seems to having lots of changes.. if STL is also changed according to it learning it is not optional.

Comment: @ss7don:  There are many changes between C++03 and C++11.  Most of them were added in order to make C++ programming easier, especially for newbies and non-experts.  However almost everything you already know about C++03 also applies in C++11.